# Hiding Ribbon on List Item Custom Form

Tags: list, infopath, custom-form

I am using InfoPath to create a custom form when users add items to a list. I am using views and my own submit button so I don't want the ribbon to be visible.  How to hide it?  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the List's ribbon select:
Customize List | Form Web Parts | Content Type Forms | New Form | Edit Web Part

Then Uncheck: Show InfoPath Ribbon or toolbar

Answer (score 0):

you can also paste the following code, on the a content editor inside embadede code, with this u can even get show hide options

```
<script type="text/javascript" unselectable="on">
function ShowRibbonRow() 
{$("#s4-ribbonrow").show(); }
function HideRibbonRow() 
{ $("#s4-ribbonrow").hide(); }
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("HideRibbonRow");
</script>
<div class="w-Ribbon" unselectable="on">
<a onclick="Javascript:ShowRibbonRow();" href="#" unselectable="on">Show</a>
<a onclick="Javascript:HideRibbonRow();" href="#" unselectable="on">Hide</a>
</div>
```